# Creation time of the timestamp is in the future. This typically indicates lack of synchronization between sender and receiver clocks

Tags: asp.net, soap, kentico

We're using Kentico's staging module to sync content from our staging server to our production server.  However, it appears the system clock on our prod server is 5 minutes slow, and at the moment we can't do anything about it because... reasons.

We're getting the following error when we try to synchronize:

> Synchronization client error: Exception occurred: An error was discovered processing the  header ---> WSE065: Creation time of the timestamp is in the future. This typically indicates lack of synchronization between sender and receiver clocks. Make sure the clocks are synchronized or use the timeToleranceInSeconds element in the microsoft.web.services3 configuration section to adjust tolerance for lack of clock synchronization.

We tried adding the `<timeToleranceInSeconds>` key to our web config as the error message states, but it doesn't seem to remedy the issue no matter what values we enter.  We've tried a reasonable 360 seconds and -360s, as well as +/-86400s to adjust time difference tolerance.  We're certain our key is in the right spot in the web config.

Is there another way we can fix this *besides* correcting the system clock of our production server?  Or, is there possibly something else wrong that we're misunderstanding?

Comment: Could you please include SOAP message header including times, time of the error message and timezone settings of your servers? Have you tried overriding also the defaultTtlInSeconds?

Comment: One more thing - did you put the timeToleranceInSeconds to the source's or target's web.config?

Comment: It was added to the source's config.  I won't be able to give you exact headers until Monday.

Comment: I think the key only makes sense on target. Give it a try...

Comment: @rocky Yep, had to add it to the target.  Put that in an answer and I'll accept, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the `timeToleranceInSeconds` key with a reasonable value to the target staging server.